# Cant print validation errors values into view with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to show validation errors after jquery ajax call, but for some reason instead of printing the actual messagge I'm getting either +value+ or +data.success+, am I appending the values wrong?

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
url: '/contactar',/*{{ action('ContactController@contactar') }}*/
    type: 'POST',
    data: 
    {
        'message_body': $("textarea[name='message']").val()
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) { 
        $('.form_valid_container').append('<span class="form_valid_text">data.success</span>');
        form.trigger("reset");
        console.log(data.success, data.errors);
    },
    error: function (data){
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        console.log(errors);
        $.each(errors , function(key , value){
            console.log('error pin');
            $('.form_error_container').append('<span class="form_error_text">+ value +</span>')
        }); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are appending the values incorrectly as shown by the syntax coloring: the whole text is in dark red.

Your String is starting with a single quote `'` so you need to end the string with `'` too before your `+ value +` :

```js
$('.form_error_container').append('<span class="form_error_text">' + value + '</span>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @pyb and original code will almost always work. However, I can see that the DIV will keep appending the errors even though the form has been reset or triggered multiple times.

Below is the code which I prefer:

**NOTE**: I have used `html` function in the success block container which will NOT append the success message always.

**NOTE**: I have cleared the `form_error_container` using `html` function before printing the error messages, so that it will not keep appending the error messages even though the form is reset or triggered multiple times.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/contactar',/*{{ action('ContactController@contactar') }}*/
    type: 'POST',
    data: 
    {
        'message_body': $("textarea[name='message']").val()
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data) { 
        $('.form_valid_container').html('<span class="form_valid_text">data.success</span>');
        form.trigger("reset");
        console.log(data.success, data.errors);
    },
    error: function (data){
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        console.log(errors);
        $('.form_error_container').html("");
        $.each(errors , function(key, value) {
            console.log('error pin');
            $('.form_error_container').append('<span class="form_error_text">' + value + '</span>')
        }); 
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Peter - if this has helped then please mark as correct and upvote. If not then please let me know how I can help. Thanks.